# Uploading multiple HttpPostedFileBase using Parallel.ForEach breaking files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parallel-processing

I have a form that uploads multiple files. My model has a `List<HttpPostedFileBase>` called `SchemaFileBases`, which is correctly binded. I need to upload these files to s3 and would like to do it in parallel. I'm unable to use asyc and await because this code is run from both ASP.Net and a queue based application that currently doesn't have async/await support (working on it).

If I change the `foreach` below to `Parallel.ForEach(this.SchemaFileBases, schemaFileBase => {`... Then I get some funkiness going on. The two files end up being mashed. Each file will contain some of the other files content after it's uploaded. `AwsDocument` is being used elsewhere in parallel so I don't think it has to do with that. Each `AwsDocument` has it's own `AmazonS3Client`.

```
    public override void UploadToS3(IMetadataParser parser)
    {
        string hash;
        string key;

        foreach (var schemaFileBase in this.SchemaFileBases)
        {
            AwsDocument aws = new AwsDocument(AwsBucket.Received);
            hash = schemaFileBase.InputStream.Md5Hash().ToByteArray().ToHex();
            key = String.Format("{0}/{1}", this.S3Prefix, schemaFileBase.FileName);

            Stream inputStream = schemaFileBase.InputStream;
            aws.UploadToS3(key, inputStream, hash);
        }
    }
```

My coworker suspect's it's something to do with how the `InputStream` on the `HttpPostedFileBase` is implemented. Perhaps it is not thread safe, and the streams are both reading from the original request at the same time? I can't imagine MS would do that though.

Multi-threaded version:

```
    public override void UploadToS3(IMetadataParser parser)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(this.SchemaFileBases, f =>
        {
            AwsDocument aws = new AwsDocument(AwsBucket.Received);
            string hash = f.InputStream.Md5Hash().ToByteArray().ToHex();
            string key = String.Format("{0}/{1}", this.S3Prefix, f.FileName);

            Stream inputStream = f.InputStream;
            aws.UploadToS3(key, inputStream, hash);
        });
    }
```

Above solution is what I tried to multi-thread it. Does not work (files get mixed up all weird).

Comment: try declaring your hash and key variables inside foreach loop and change to threading?

Comment: Good point on the hash/key. I didn't think I needed to worry but maybe the s3 client grabs the key a few times from memory per upload. What do you mean by 'change to threading'?

Comment: change to Parallel.ForEach by instantiating those variables inside block; does it work?

Comment: Didn't work. Editing question with code I used.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why aws instantiation went out of Parallel block?

Comment: Oops. Updated code to what I just ran (aws declared inside loop). Each call to "UploadToS3" creates its own AmazonS3Client so I wasn't too worried. Error still exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100190/discussion-between-techspider-and-dave).